# Probability additivity axiom on countably infinite set

Tags: probability

I just have a simple question about the additivity axiom on countably infinite set, which I can't get my head around it. If any outcome in the sample space has greater or equal 0 probability (a positive number), how can we make sure that the overall probability of this infinite set is less than 1?

Comment: For example if the probability space is $\Bbb N$ and the probability of getting $n$ is $2^{-n}$

Comment: Have you learned about convergent series? Infinite sums of positive numbers can be finite.

Comment: If $0<a:=\sum_n a_n < \infty$ is any convergent series of non-negative terms, $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$, then $P(X=n)=a_n/a$ defines a valid PMF such that $ \sum_n P(X=n)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is some formal discussion about convergent series.  Here’s a more intuitive idea:

Your entire sample space has probability one.
Now pick some event.  The event is made up of disjoint outcomes in the sample space.  In other words , the event is a subset of the sample space.

By monotonicity , the probability of the event has to be less than or equal to one.